# Google Page Speed Insights is recommending inline styling and complaining about render blocking JS. Are these even relevant?

Tags: seo, google, performance, page-speed

Sometimes, I feel like Google is living in its own bubble. Most of the time, when you run your page through their tool, it complains either about "page rendering blocking JS", "how you should save 1,8MB of bandwidth" or "how you should just inline your styling, because".

Both of those things are mostly irrelevant and also a matter of opinion, so this brings me back to the title of the question: Does it really matter chasing the "perfect A" on insights?

Comment: *Sometimes, I feel like Google is living in its own bubble.* **You think??** ;-) I do not take Google or most any of these sites too seriously. They are suggestions. And like you say, they are based upon someones opinion. Who says they are right? Cheers!!

Comment: Don't view it as "these are items you must fix."   Rather view it as "These could potentially be problematic."  For many sites render blocknig JS could easily add the async attribute.

Answer (score 5):

One of the Google guys, Paul Lewis, said achieving 85 or better should be your goal. Of course those things you mention matter. Both to Google and, especially, users!

Page render blocking is blocking your page. Is it a problem? Maybe not for you but Google is suggesting you look into it and make sure. (Thanks!). Saving 1.8MB of bandwidth? Holy cow! Maybe my images are too big. If not, what is it? Inline styling? What a pain. Are they wrong? No!

Anything that makes your web site load faster is always good for the user! Thanks Google!

But overall, [Paul agrees with you](https://aerotwist.com/blog/my-performance-audit-workflow/).

> Now the thing to bear in mind about PSI is that it’s distilling down a
>   collection of very good (and broad) set of rules and seeing how your
>   site measures up. It doesn’t really care about context or what you
>   chose to do or not do as a team. As such I just tend to see PSI as a
>   checklist of things that are somewhere between “a good idea” and
>   “crucial”, and I don’t aim for a score of 100 across the board.
>
> The reason I’m not going to pin all my hopes on a PSI score of 100 is
>   that it may make my development more difficult. Inlining CSS and
>   JavaScript to pages is one recommendation that it makes, but I think
>   more context is required here.

[And even Google will say that.](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/about)

> A higher score is better and a score of 85 or above indicates that the
>   page is performing well.